# Getting NSManagedObject from another NSManagedObjectContext (referring the same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator)

Tags: iphone, core-data

i have got two different NSManagedObjectContexts both referring to the same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, say context1 and context2.

I have an NSManagedObject out of context1. As I would like to edit it, not knowing whether it will be saved afterwards, I would like to get that object from context2. Context2 could be just trashed in the case that I do not want to save the NSManagedObject. In case of a save, I will merge context2 in context1.

But how do I get the object from context2? Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to request the object with an predicate xyz=[NSManagedObject objectId]? And what does xyz have to be in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the target NSManagedObjectContext, i.e.

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    myArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

Addition to your comment:

```
context2object = [myEntityArrayFromContext2 objectAtIndex:[myEntityArrayFromContext1 indexOfObject:context1object]];
```

Comment: Right. That's what I did to get the managed object from context1. But now the user decides to edit that object. That is the reason why i need that same object from context2. So how do i get that? Through the objectID?

Comment: I'm not shure whether you know what I meant ;)

I got all objects using your code above.

It returned me an array of 5 Objects of type "MyEntity".
Clear so far.
Now I take for example the third element out of that array. This element is of course an Object of class "MyEntity".
Now my question I tried to ask obove:
How do I get that third Object of class type "MyEntity" out of contexts2? Or more general: How do I associate an existing NSManagedObject to another context?